# Was "St. Bartholomew's Day massacre" what people used before Kristallnacht happened?

Tags: twentieth-century-english

The New York Times' first article on Adolf Hitler, "Hitler New Power in Germany", written in 1922 (but still paywalled), referred to fears of a [St. Bartholomew's Day massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Bartholomew%27s_Day_massacre). Was that the standard way of referring to an incident of racist violence back then, before we had Kristallnacht?

Doing an NGrams search for [St. Bartholomew's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=St.%20Bartholomew%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSt.%20Bartholomew%20%27s%3B%2Cc0) doesn't have a sharp drop after Kristallnacht occurred.

Comment: It's probably still the main term - I'm not familiar with Kristallnacht being used in a generic sense at all.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bartholomew+Massacre%2CBartholomew+Day+Massacre%2CMassacre+of+St.+Bartholomew+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=8&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBartholomew%20Massacre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBartholomew%20Day%20Massacre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMassacre%20of%20St.%20Bartholomew%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I've never read/heard *Kristallnacht* used metaphorically.  *St. Barthlomew's Day* a handful of times, though.